# Bohr sets and lattice in $\mathbb{R}^k$

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, additive-combinatorics

I was watching Gowers' lectures on additive combinatorics, and in them, he proved some structural theorems about Bohr sets. You can find the lectures [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UMzBhA91lIs&list=PLOft35kj95aaPDB3YBDd4mmS8xBov_rL6&index=14&t=1136s). Before I ask my question, let me provide some definitions.

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group, and let $\widehat{G}$ be a a group of characters on $G$.

**Definition 1. (Bohr set)** Let $\Gamma\subset \widehat{G}$ and $\delta\in [0,2]$. The *Bohr set* with frequency set $\Gamma$ and width $\delta$ is the set $\text{Bohr}(\Gamma; \delta)= \big\{x\in G: \chi(x)\in e([-\delta,\delta])\ \text{for all} \ \chi\in \Gamma\big\}$, where $e(\alpha)=e^{2\pi i \alpha}$.

**Definition 2. (Lattice)** A subgroup $\Lambda$ of $\mathbb{R}^k$ is called a *lattice* if it is a discrete subgroup that generates all of $\mathbb{R}^k$ as a vector space.

**Definition 3. (Freiman homomorphism and isomorphism)** Let $k\geq 1$, and let $A,B$ be additive sets with ambient groups $G$ and $H$, respectively. A Freiman homomorphism of order $k$ from $(A,G)$ to $(B,H)$ (or more succinctly from $A$ to $B$) is a map $\phi:A\to B$ with the property that $a_1+\dots+a_k=a'_1+\dots+a'_k \Longrightarrow  \phi (a_1)+\dots+\phi(a_k)=\phi(a'_1)+\dots+\phi(a'_k)$
for all $a_1,\dots,a_k,a'_1,\dots,a'_k\in A$. If in addition there is an inverse map $\phi^{-1}:B\to A$ which is a Freiman homomorphism of order $k$ from $(B,H)$ to $(A,G)$, then we say that $\phi$ is a Freiman isomorphism of order $k$, and that $(A,G)$ and $(B,H)$ are Freiman isomorphic of order $k$.

**Lemma. (Structure of Bohr sets)** Let $N$ be a prime, and let $\Gamma\subset \widehat{\mathbb{Z}_N}$ be a set of nontrivial characters of size $k$. Also, let $r\in \mathbb{N}$ and $\delta\in (0,\frac{1}{2r})$. Then the Bohr set $\text{Bohr}(\Gamma;\delta)$ is Freiman isomorphic of order $r$ to $\Lambda\cap [-\delta N,\delta N]^k$ for some lattice $\Lambda$ in $\mathbb{R}^k$.

I understood the proof of the above result and it is a pretty deep result and my question is not about that. In the proof, the lattice $\Lambda$ is generated by some vector $\vec{u}=(u_1,\dots,u_k)$ and $N\vec{e}_1=(N,0,\dots,0),\dots,N\vec{e}_k=(0,0,\dots,N)$. In other words,
$$\Lambda=\{n_0\vec{u}+n_1N\vec{e}_1+\dots+n_kN\vec{e}_k:n_0,n_1,\dots,n_k \in \mathbb{Z}\},$$ where coordinates $u_i$ are nonzero elements $\mathbb{Z}_N$ which can be identified with integers. Then Gowers says that after a linear transformation, the set $\Lambda \cap [-\delta N,\delta N]^k$ can be converted into the intersection of $\mathbb{Z}^k$ with a convex body.

*Here is my question:* I am a bit confused with the last sentence. I suppose that in order to demonstrate this, one needs to construct an isomorphism $f$ from $\mathbb{R}^k$ to $\mathbb{R}^k$ such that $f(\Lambda)=\mathbb{Z}^k$. Am I correct? If so, could anyone please show me how to do that? I believe it should be relatively straightforward, but I have no idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\Z{\mathbb{Z}}\def\R{\mathbb{R}}$By definition $\Lambda$ is a subgroup of $\Z^k$ containing a basis of $\R^k$. It is a basic fact of free abelian groups (following from the existence of Smith normal form) that any subgroup of $\Z^k$ is isomorphic to $\Z^\ell$ for some $\ell \le k$. Since $\Lambda$ contains a basis of $\R^k$ it follows that $\Lambda \cong \Z^k$. In other words there is an isomorphism $f : \Lambda \to \Z^k$. Since $\Lambda \le \R^k$ and a basis for $\Lambda$ is a basis for $\R^k$ we can extend $f$ to a linear isomorphism $f : \R^k \to \R^k$ such that $f(\Lambda) = \Z^k$.
Now let $B_0 = [-\delta N, \delta N]^k$. Then $f(\Lambda \cap B_0) = \Z^k \cap B$ where $B = f(B_0)$ is the image of $B_0$ under $B$. Since $B_0$ is a convex body, so is $B$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and I apologize for the late reply! In the beginning of your post, you mentioned that it follows from the existence of Smith normal form (SNF). However, I don't think that you need SNF here. We already know that $\Lambda$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^k$, and hence $\Lambda$ is a free abelian group of rank $\ell \leq k$, implying $\Lambda \cong \mathbb{Z}^{\ell}$. In this deduction, we use the result that a subgroup $H$ of a free abelian group $F$ is free, and $\text{rk}(H) \leq \text{rk}(F)$.

Comment: @RFZ That fact is usually proved using SNF. In fact one can also deduce the existence of SNF from that fact, so the two things are equivalent.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! It helped me clarify my thoughts.